# What are the procedure for a B747-400 wheel change?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, boeing-747, tire

And what are the required tools? I am fascinated by how you do a B747-400 wheel change.

Comment: https://youtu.be/Bh6-1qL6dgY

Comment: 1) Jack up a wheel. 2) Unbolt old one. 3) Bolt on new one. 4) Lower jack. Source: Watched it being done while standing about 50' away on the tarmac of Ben Gurion Airport c.1984, while waiting to load our dogs to fly home to the USA. (Security, even in Israel, was different then.)